# Fetching Cities dynamically in Asp.net HTML control

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I have a HTML dropdown list for countries. Now I want to populate the City dropdown accordingly using ajax

```
<select class="form-control" id="ddCountry" runat="server" tabindex="8"></select>

<select class="form-control" id="ddCity" runat="server" tabindex="9"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#ddCountry').on('change', function () {

            var storeData = { countryId: this.value }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "UserRegistration.aspx/GetCities",
                data: JSON.stringify(storeData),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("The data in list is "+data);
                },
                error: error
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My method on .cs page is as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static List<CityBO> GetCities(string countryId)
        {
             //returning cities
        }
```

The problem is I am able to fetch the data in GetCities method but not able to show it in the ddCity list because it is a HTML control and the method is static, so

`ddCity.Items.AddRange(list_of_countries)` is not working as ddCity is not being recognized in static method. Please tell how to fill the dropdown list.

Comment: You need bind the data from getcities inside your jquery success function not in the web method. Web methods are static and you can not access form control in static context

Comment: Sir can you please tell the success function for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access controls in static method. You need to return list of cities from webmethod and fill dropdown using javascript.In success method of ajax write code like this.

```
success: function (data) {
    fillDropDown(data.d);
}

function fillDropDown(data){
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
          html += "<option value='" + data[i].ValueField+ "'>" + 
                   data[i].TextField+ "</option>";
    }
     $("select[id$=ddlCity]").html(html);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir but can you please give me the code of how to fill it using javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax success function given below.

```
success: function (data) 
{
 var lankanListArray = JSON.parse(data.d);
 // running a loop
 $.each(lankanListArray, function (index, value) 
 {
  $("#ddlCity").append($("<option></option>").val(this.name).html(this.value));              
 });
}
```